# Unique in mongoose not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have my example mongoose schema as below

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const  Schema = mongoose.Schema

 const exampleSchema = new Schema ({
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        mobile:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
    })

 module.exports ={Driver: mongoose.model('Driver', driverSchema)}
```

Now the thing is that unique in mobile is working fine, but in email it allows me to insert duplicate email address.

Comment: This might be because there were record/s with that email on the db before you specified `unique: true`, have you tried dropping the database then try duplicate using this schema?

Comment: Can you post your test code

Comment: @SASSY_ROG You can give answere to my question. I will approve it.

Comment: Don't worry @SavanPadaliya it's not much to be an answer, there's not much technical detail

Comment: @SASSY_ROG I appreciate your help. Thank you once again. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to I have records in collection before giving `unique: true`.

Answer (score 1):

You had better to create your indexes in mongodb shell.

In the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) they state:

> In a production environment, you should create your [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)
>   using the MongoDB shell rather  than relying on mongoose to do it for
>   you.   The unique option for schemas is convenient for development and
>   documentation,   but mongoose is not an index management solution.

So I would remove unique options in schema, and can create the unique indexes in mongodb shell like this:

```js
db.drivers.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } )
db.drivers.createIndex( { "mobile": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```